# Match error message column values to column names used in query

Tags: mysql

So with query:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_0_col, id_1_col, text_01_col, text_02_col);
```

An error is produced:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '11535-1013-FRA-TZN-MON-TON' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

In query 4 columns were used. Some of the values in those columns are hyphenated. The error message produced by mysql uses hyphen to delimit column values.

How would you match values from error message back to column names used in query to build a subsequent query to find offending row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the offending rows (duplicate rows), you can simply use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`. Following query will get all the combinations which have more than one rows corresponding to them:

```
SELECT 
  id_0_col, id_1_col, text_01_col, text_02_col
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY id_0_col, id_1_col, text_01_col, text_02_col
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now, to get all those rows, you can simply wrap this query in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and join back to get all the "offending rows":

```
SELECT 
  t.* 
FROM your_table_name AS t 
JOIN (
       SELECT 
         id_0_col, id_1_col, text_01_col, text_02_col
       FROM your_table_name 
       GROUP BY id_0_col, id_1_col, text_01_col, text_02_col
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
     ) AS dt ON dt.id_0_col = t.id_0_col
                AND dt.id_1_col = t.id_1_col
                AND dt.text_01_col = t.text_01_col
                AND dt.text_02_col = t.text_02_col
```

Comment: There does not seem to any other way. I'll go with your suggestion.